# Select specific data from data only if certain fields can be grouped by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data:

```
ID        Date         Num        ClientID         Dest
--------------------------------------------------------
123       04/29/2021   -2222      H1234            -1
123       04/29/2021   1          H1234            3
345       04/29/2021   -2222      H3456            -1
345       04/29/2021   1          H8888            .1
```

BTW: this does not include all the fields, just what I'm currently using for my query.

For every ID in the above table I'll always have 2 records. There are 2 scenarios that can take place:

1. As for ID = 123, the ClientID is the same
2. As for ID = 345, the ClientID is different

I'm trying to return the following data:

```
ID        Date         Num        ClientID         Dest
123       04/29/2021   1          H1234            3
```

The reason I'm returning only this row is because:

- I only want 1 row per ID, where the ClientID is the same for both rows
- Only need the record that does not have -2222, where the CLientID is the same for both rows
- If the ClientID is different for the same ID (ex: 345), then completely skip these records.

Now the numbers for DEST can vary, so we can't always rely that one will be -1 and the other will be positive, however the NUM field will always have -2222 and 1 for the 2nd row (which is the row that I'd want to be returned)

I'm not sure how best to do this, I guess I thought about the alternative of just creating a CTE, and then counting the ClientID and if Count = 2 then select the data. The problem I find is with DEST field, I know that I can do Max(NUM) but since DEST field can very I wouldn't know how to select it.

Here is what I tried:

```
WITH Ranking AS (
    SELECT Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID,c.date1,c.ClientID ORDER BY num 
     asc)x, c.*
FROM cte c
)

SELECT * FROM Ranking WHERE x = 2
```

I'm not if this is a good apprach, I guess it does the job but any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the ever-useful `window functions` with `row_number` to select which pair to use and `lead` to check if both ClientIds are the same. This would work regardless if the specific values you have should change, plus is more performant than hitting the table twice:

```
select id, date, num, clientid, Dest from ( 
    select *, 
    Row_Number() over(partition by id order by num) rn, 
    case when Lead(clientid) over(partition by id order by num)=clientid then 1 else 0 end same
    from t
)t
where rn=1 and same=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select all rows where Num isn't -2222 and the ID is in a subquery grouped by id and having only one distinct client id.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tbl GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ClientId) = 1)
    AND Num != -2222
```